# Capitalizing document names

Tags: capitalization

Does anyone know if I need to capitalize document names in this sentence?

Created and maintained comprehensive project documentation; Business Case, Project Charter, and Project Plans.

In other words, does Business Case, Project Charter and Project Plans need to be capitalized.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: A side note, that should be a colon `:`, not a semicolon `;`

Comment: Are we going to be proofreading your entire resume this week?

Answer (score 0):

You capitalize something when it is a proper noun, i.e. when it identifies a specific thing.

So if you are writing a document that lays out a specific business case (say the one for your company) and its title is "Business Case" then you capitalize it.

> "I wrote the document called "Business Case."

If you want to describe that you are writing a document of a particular kind, such as one that is of the kind "business case" then you don't capitalize it.

> "I wrote the business case document for our company. It was called 'Acme Inc. Business Case 2016.'"

Comment: Thanks you SO much DJ!!  I am not referring to a specific document.  I'm just listing the types of documents I have written before.

Comment: So I will lower case.  I have a follow up question for you.

Comment: In the sentence:  

Created and maintained comprehensive project documentation; Business Case, Project Charter, and Project Plans. 

If I created multiple documents of each type do I that have to make each plural or just the last plural?

Created and maintained comprehensive project documentation; Business Cases, Project Charters, and Project Plans. 

or 

Created and maintained comprehensive project documentation; Business Case, Project Charter, and Project Plans.

Comment: jj if you want to ask another question, please use the 'ask question' button at the top.